# Show that $5\mathbb{Z}-5\mathbb{Z}=5\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

**My proof.**

*Lemma.* $\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

Proof. ($\Rightarrow$) Let $z\in \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z}$. Then, there is $z_{1},z_{2} \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $z=z_{1}-z_{2}$. So, $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.Thus,$\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z} \subset\mathbb {Z}$.

($\Leftarrow$) Let $z'\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $z'-0\in\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $\mathbb {Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z}$. 
     Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, since we have $\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$, $5\mathbb{Z}-5\mathbb{Z}=5(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z})=5\mathbb{Z}$.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: How do you know $5{\Bbb Z}-5{\Bbb Z}=5({\Bbb Z}-{\Bbb Z})$?  Do you have a previous theorem which says this is true?  Remember you are taking about sets and you cannot just assume they follow the same rules as numbers.

Comment: @David I know by the definition. So, $5\mathbb{Z}-5\mathbb{Z}$={$5z_{1}-5z_{2}$: $z_{1},z_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$}={$5(z_{1}-z_{2})$: $z_{1},z_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$}=$5(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{Z})$, isn't it?

Comment: The idea is: if we subtract two multiples of 5 do we obtain a multiple of 5? This is more simple than what you did.

Comment: @BeniBogosel Did you see above my comment?

Comment: Kahler, that comment is fine, but the point is that you didn't write it down in your proof!  In fact, your comment pretty much is a proof of the whole thing and the rest of your original answer is scarcely necessary.

Comment: I assume that $A\setminus B\ne A - B$, the definition of the first is $A\setminus B=\{x\in A : x\notin B\}$

Comment: @Masacroso I did not understand your comment.

Comment: @David So, can you show my question since I can check my proof?

Comment: @Kahler: If you include your comment the proof is fine

Comment: @BeniBogosel So, what is problem for my proof of the question?

Comment: @Kahler the definition of [set difference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Difference). So I assume that the operator "-" is not the set difference.

Comment: @Masacroso I did not understand issue in my proof. Can you explain clearly?

Comment: @Kahler, Im not saying there is a problem... just that I usually see the use of "-" as the set difference operator, but this is not the case. If "-" would be the set difference operator then $\Bbb Z -\Bbb Z =\emptyset$. Your proof is completely correct but it would be better a little more of context about the use of the notation and definitions.

Comment: @Masacroso Okey,  I see. Thanks.

Comment: Just put a line in the proof showing that $(5\Bbb{Z}-5\Bbb{Z}) =5(\Bbb{Z}-\Bbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to *use a lemma*, it may be better just to imitate it in writing the direct proof.

Using your notation, we first prove $5\mathbb{Z} - 5\mathbb{Z} \subset 5\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof:** An arbitrary element in $5\mathbb{Z} - 5\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $5a - 5b$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. By the distributive law of multiplication over subtraction, we have $5a-5b = 5(a-b) \in 5\mathbb{Z}$, where the final inclusion follows from the closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ under subtraction. Thus, the desired containment holds.

Next, we show that $5\mathbb{Z} \subset 5\mathbb{Z} - 5\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof:** An arbitrary element in $5\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $5a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Next, observe that:

$$5a = 5a - 0 = 5a - 5(0) \in 5\mathbb{Z} - 5\mathbb{Z}$$

where the final inclusion follows because $a, 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the desired containment holds.

**So:** Combining the two proofs above, we have the desired equality of sets. **QED**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof based on your own comment.

First, let $z\in 5{\Bbb Z}-5{\Bbb Z}$.  Then $z=5z_1-5z_2$ for some integers $z_1$ and $z_2$.  But then $z=5(z_1-z_2)$, and $z_1-z_2$ is an integer, so $z\in5{\Bbb Z}$.

Conversely, let $z\in5{\Bbb Z}$.  Then $z=5z_1$ for some integer $z_1$, and so
$$z=5(z_1-0)=5z_1-5\times0\ .$$
But $z_1\in{\Bbb Z}$ so $5z_1\in5{\Bbb Z}$; and $0\in{\Bbb Z}$ so $5\times0\in5{\Bbb Z}$; so $z\in5{\Bbb Z}-5{\Bbb Z}$.  This completes the proof.

**Simpler version of the second part**: let $z\in5{\Bbb Z}$; then $z=z-5\times0$ which is in $5{\Bbb Z}-5{\Bbb Z}$.